# I want to use MD5 Class to do some encryption work，but I can't find it?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, md5

There is only *System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates* in the namespace **System.Security.Cryptography**
But I want to use the   *System.Security.Cryptography.MD5*
I use visual studio 2012
And I want to develop a windows phone 8 app
Can u tell me why???

Comment: Unless you specifically need MD5 (for instance, for compatibility with another app), you should consider using SHA instead. MD5 isn't safe anymore.

Comment: @KooKiz But the China Moblie has to do it this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an MD5 implementation in [Cimbalino Windows Phone Toolkit](http://cimbalino.org).

Just to it to your project (use [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/Cimbalino.Phone.Toolkit)), add the following to the top of the code file:

```c#
using Cimbalino.Phone.Toolkit.Extensions;
```

and then just use it in your code like this:

```c#
var myString = "this is my string data";

var myStringBytes = myString.GetBytes(); // this will get the UTF8 bytes for the string

var md5Hash = myStringBytes.ComputeMD5Hash().ToBase64String();
```

Comment: Cimbalino Windows Phone Toolkit looks great,but I can't find a method can return me a 16 character MD5,which is md5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.Default.GetBytes(ConvertString)), 4, 8)

Answer (score 0):

It is because MD5 is "insecure" (see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5).

You can use [M5 Class](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SilverlightMD5/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=5701) (I used it for my wp8 project).

Regards

Comment: Can you be more specific? With one sample ?

Answer (score 0):

Windows phone doesn't support MD5 cryptography, here is a [good example of md5 implementation in c#](http://farazmahmood.wordpress.com/projects/md5-implementation-in-c/)